# aws s3 get object not reading whole file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am reading an S3 Object containing JSON text. This was working fine for small number of elements like 4.

After it's grown a little (I mean less than 1 MB overall file size !) The file is chopped.

I thought `get_object` method gives the whole object . What am I missing that the entire object isn't read.

```
 s3client=boto3.client('s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
 Obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=x, Key=y)
 jobStream=Obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
 jsonObj=json.loads(jobStream)
 print(json.dumps(jsonObj,indent=2))
```

JSON is properly formed...The output is truncated randomly.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to decode the object with the `json.load` if the S3 Object didn't return valid JSON. You can check that the object stored in the S3 bucket was _put_ with the right information and is not truncated.

Comment: Yes It has nothing to do with json even sample text file i uploaded is getting chopped  ex: i uploaded alphabitically arranged  words like ...head -5 ./venv3.6/testtext.txt
aah
aahed
aaron
aback
abacus
....... but the output is from words startign letter C and the end gets chopped off tooo . i feel like i am missing to iterate thru chunks ....

Answer (score 0):

My potential suggestions would be as follows;

1. Similar to what you already have

   ```
   s3client=boto3.client('s3',config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'))
   Obj = s3client.get_object(Bucket=x, Key=y)
   text=Obj["Body"].read().decode()
   print(text['anything']) # Use your desired JSON Key for your value
   ```
2. Get file with Object

   ```
   s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
   content_object = s3.Object('test', 'sample_json.txt')
   file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
   json_content = json.loads(file_content)
   print(json_content['anything']) # Use your desired JSON Key for your value
   ```

Comment: does not work ...json_content['anything'] returns for existing json element ....thats the whole problem ....

Comment: i mean dosent return anything for existing element

Answer (score 0):

Ignore i was uploading wrong file , i was in wrong dir

Comment: Feel free to delete the question if the information is invalid.